# create a cron schedule expression aws that triggers on 14 may and june 18

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a schedule expression that triggers on may 14 and june 18 at 10:00 am.

Is this valid?

```
cron(0 0 10 14,18 5,6 ? *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's going to run 4 times:

- May 14
- May 18
- June 14
- June 18

I don't think you can schedule two specific days of different months with a single cron expression. You'll have to create two cron triggers for the two dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS console UI to validate the expression. It's in EventBrdige -> Rules -> Create rule. To prove Mark B's point:

[image]